# javascript for loop to select all divs in another div

Tags: javascript

I'm new to using flask and javascript.

I have div's being created with information like this

```
<div id="divholder">
  {%for i in volcanoinfo%}
    <div class="volcdiv">
      <p id="volcanolat" style="display: none;">{{ i['vlat'] }}</p>
      <p id="volcanolon" style="display: none;">{{ i['vlng'] }}</p>
    </div>
  {%endfor%}
</div>
```

I would then like to access each 'volcdiv' using a for loop  for use else where.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Research [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Also, just FYI, you need to remove the `id` attributes you set on the content in the loop. That will create duplicates with the same `id` which is invalid HTML. Replace them with `class` if you need some custom grouping identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.volcdiv div');
```

this will give you `items` as a NodeList.  You can then use the spread functionality to turn that into an array and then iterate through:

```
[...items].forEach(item => {
   // iterating through each div
});
```

alsio as @Rory stated, you don't want to re-use an `id`.

Comment: I believe you can use `forEach()` directly on a `NodeList` without having to convert it to an array.

Comment: @mykaf: yep, [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) is a thing.